# How to view code coverage as html for Flutter in Windows?

Tags: flutter, dart, code-coverage, lcov

I did `flutter test --coverage`

A `lcov.info` was generated under `coverage`

I want to convert this into html but I don't find a tool for Windows.

On linux, you just do:

```
sudo apt-get update -qq -y
sudo apt-get install lcov -y
```

Then you do

`genhtml coverage/lcov.info -o coverage/html`

I am on Windows and 
`'genhtml' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ok I found it. I will leave the anwser here in case it maybe helpful for anyone.

Actually genhtml is a `perl` script. If you are have git bash installed, you should have perl already. Try `where perl` on the `cmd` and it will show you the path.

For me it was at `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\perl.exe`

Now create a file called `genhtml.perl` inside your flutter project root directory. (Make sure to `.gitignore` it)
Then in the file, copy and paste the content this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/valbok/lcov/master/genhtml.perl

Finally open git bash and run `$ ./genhtml.perl ./coverage/lcov.info -o coverage/html` .

Check You are done html files at `coverage/html`.

On android studio, select `index.html` then `CTRL+SHIFT+C` to copy the file path.

Open Chrome and on the url bar add `file:///`+`CTRL+V`. Tap enter. You are done.

**PS :** Who so ever is facing an error like `No common filename prefix found!` or some other issue, they can try replacing content of `genhtml.perl` file from below link.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/linux-test-project/lcov/master/bin/genhtml

Answer (score 4):

set `genhtml` variable to where the genthml perl script of lcov located to `PATH`

for me, it's on

> C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\lcov\tools\bin

then run the command
`genhtml coverage/lcov.info -o coverage/html` from git bash instead of terminal

`-o` is shorthand for `--output-file`

see this [article](https://fredgrott.medium.com/lcov-on-windows-7c58dda07080)

Answer (score 0):

1. [choco install lcov](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/lcov)

   - genhtml: `%programdata%\chocolatey\lib\lcov\tools\bin\genhtml`
   - perl.exe: `C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe`
2. `perl.exe myGenhtml.perl MyInput.lcov -o myOutputDirPath`

   > [myGenhtml.perl](https://github.com/linux-test-project/lcov/blob/521e31949b5571d9093e9e85462cb137dded05b4/bin/genhtml#L1-L10890) which is a file you can copy and use directly, or modify some of the parameters inside it.
3. Open `<myOutputDirPath>/index.html` to see the result.

Here is a [script](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/powershell/blob/80666f146552519ea2d57e642ca1e055f087a4c2/src/coverage/lcov.psm1#L1-L80) writing with Powershell that may help you run.